# Cordova Facebook login returns only accessToken

Tags: javascript, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I'm using [the official Cordova Facebook plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) to implement Facebook login in my mobile app. I have been trying for days to make the following code work but I don't know where is the problem. I just need to retrieve the user email, name and gender. I get only the accesstoken, I know that I need to call the API function but it also returns the accesstoken

```
<div onclick="login();apiTest();">Login with Facebook</div>
<script>
        var login = function () {
            facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["public_profile"],
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
        }

        var apiTest = function () {
            facebookConnectPlugin.api( "me/?fields=id,email,name,gender",
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
        }
</script>
```

Please help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until the login is actually done, it´s asynchronous. Also, you need the email permission to get the email:

```
<div onclick="login();">Login with Facebook</div>
<script>
        var login = function () {
            facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["email", "public_profile"],
                function (response) {
                    facebookConnectPlugin.api( "me/?fields=id,email,name,gender",
                        function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                        function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
                },
                function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another error now
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at facebookConnectPlugin.js:181
var exec = require("cordova/exec");

Comment: you can find a lot of information about that error with google, this may help you: https://github.com/ionic-team/ng-cordova/issues/446